# How to fix left and right sidebar and remains centre main content scrollable upside?

Tags: php, css, html, web

Hi I am stuck at a point.

Please tell me

How to I fixed my left and right sidebar and only leave main content scrollable.

**(Please don't use bootstrap anywhere because I didn't use it in my project.)**

Please use reference image of PDF file attached because I have better explained with images that actual I want.

[image: Reference JPG View / Download here]

[Reference JPG View / Download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hxDZDrQ5iYvvlbo3CYOP_xRwgg5dEvg5)

[Reference PDF View / Download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pslNCsyNKExVQr3PvvCXZYMSfgjDI3Qw)

[Reference PPTX View / Download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sY-UYBo0GQp9DQFpTXOTuANGBgpuOAtZ)

Please let me know if something not cleared.
You can also take example of [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To make things being fixed just add `position: fixed;` in css. And for those elements that you want the content to be scrollable you must define height or max-height and overflow, eg.:

```
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
```